# How can I add volume control to this setup?

Tags: audio

I have one receiver and one subwoofer that routes high-range signals to 2 speakers.

I have 4 speakers in total.

Two front speakers and subwoofer connect to the receiver.

The two back speakers connect to the subwoofer.

The subwoofer has its own gain knob but it only controls the subwoofer, not the 2 back speakers.

The receiver volume control works on all speakers.

I need to adjust the 2 back speakers to not be so loud relative to the other speakers.

What's the best way to add this type of volume control?

Comment: I'm confused. Can you post a wiring diagram of your speaker setup, please?

Answer (score 2):

How about an [lpad](http://www.parts-express.com/parts-express-speaker-l-pad-attenuator-100w-stereo-1-shaft-8-ohm--260-264)?  Looks like it'll maintain your speaker impedance and adjust your volume.

[image]

From the descritpion:

> L-pads adjust the relative volume of drivers connected to them by placing added resistance in series. At the same time, a counter-resistance is placed in parallel with the driver to maintain a constant impedance which allows the original crossover design to be used. L-pads are to be placed in between the amplifier and speaker, or in between the crossover and driver. This stereo L-pad is rated at 100 watts RMS, is designed to be used with two 8 ohm loads, features a 1" shaft length, and comes with mounting hardware, faceplate, and volume control knob.

[image]